# Starting Another Activity on InfoWindowClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity, infowindow

I am simply trying to navigate on Another `Activity` from my `FragmentActivity` having `GoogleMap` there. I have following code for `InfoWindowClickListener`

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            String distance[] = marker.getSnippet().split(" - ");
            String distanceString = distance[0];
            String idString = marker.getId();
            String stationid = markershashmap.get(idString);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent dockitdetailsIntent = new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();

            dockitdetailsIntent.putExtra("stationId", stationid);
            dockitdetailsIntent.putExtra("distance", distanceString);

            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Activity Name",
                    dockitdetailsIntent);
        }
    });
```

But when I click the InfoWindow, my device hangs and then I have to force close the not responding app. When i use `startActivity(dockitdetailsIntent)` it works fine but Tab removes. But I want to use the Next Activity into the similar tabs. Please suggest me why my device hangs out and doesn't respond.

Comment: Suggestion just try: pass getparent() into your Intent dockitdetailsIntent = new Intent(
                    getParent(), AnotherActivity.class);

Comment: If you are using **TabGroupActivity** then you must use  **getParent()** instead of  **getApplicationContext()**

Comment: @MD Tried many times but no solutions. Device hanges totally

Comment: Now see my Answer. It is working in my case. try this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Handler and Put Intent logic into this like below:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker m1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                        String[] str2=str.split("contactID");
                            Message mesg = new Message();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("contact_id", str2[1]);
                            mesg.setData(b);
                            handler.sendMessage(mesg);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

And now create one handler like below:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b = msg.getData();

        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        b1.putString("ContactID", b.getString("contact_id"));
        b1.putBoolean("showBack", true);
        Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), ContactDetails2.class);
        edit.putExtras(b1);

        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("ContactDetails2", edit);

    }
};
```

Try this. It's working in my case

Comment: Let me integrate but why device freezes?

Comment: Its working fine... However we must be aware of problem. Can you please tell me if you are aware of it?

Comment: I m not aware of this but i got this solution from my logcat when i faced this issue my logcat said "can't implement a hanlder". so just implement this logic. Nothing else dude

Comment: Thanks bud +100 for solution